# Angular 2+ | ng test environment variable

Tags: angular, logging, environment-variables

Problem: I have a service that handles all the errors in my app, I would like to disable the logging in the service in case I am running unit tests. ( since I am testing failures in the unit tests, my consoles gets filled with logging ).

Possible solution: I thought it would make sense to use an environment variable. Ex: a `logging` variable in my `environment.test.ts` file, however, I soon realised there is no way of running `ng test` with a different environment ( it defaults to development ).

Does anyone have another idea to remove logging when running unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "unit tests" - do you mean unit tests or are you just using a unit testing framework to do integration tests?

If you're doing unit tests and you're not specifically testing the logging/error service, then you should stub (or mock) that service in your tests.

An example. If you want to test a service that has a dependency on the logging service, that dependency should be substituted with a "dummy" service that does not log to your console window. That "dummy" service is either a stub (nothing gets recorded, and probably just returns empty/static values when called), or it can be a mock (it will record how/when/with what it was called, for you to later check in the test).

Either way, when you do a unit test, you should only hit code specifically for that *unit* (as small a unit as possible - a method, or sometimes several methods if the calling method calls other (perhaps private) methods on the same class). You should never be testing more than one class per unit test. You will often have several tests for one class and even several tests for one method in one class.

If you're in reality doing integration testing - I won't stop you - then you can still stub out functionality that you do not want to be run - replace the logging service in your test setup.

For all this to work - you need a somewhat good architecture. Since you're testing typescript/javascript, replacing services is easier than it would be in a strongly typed language - if your architecture is not prepared for it - more specifically if you're not using dependency injection...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am doing unit testing, I just didn't mock the logging service as I thought it wasn't necessary, I will follow your advice and mock it to get rid of the logging.